# Is it possible to override a module in CJS or NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, browserify, commonjs

I am importing a module in my application using 'require'. And I want to change the functionality of that module in my JS file and starting from this step, if someone require the module, the changed chings should affect. Is it possible to achieve this? It is not exact but something like this.

```
//module1.js
module.exports = function(p,q) {
retrun p+q;
}

//app.js

var change  = require(./module1);// I 'require'd it here just to modify,actually there is no dependency
var dependency = require(./dependency1) 
//modifying the module1 functionality to something like 
// module.exports = function() {return p-q;}

//dependency1.js
var use1 = require(./module1)
log(use1(8,3))// should result in '5'

enter code here
```

Any help ais highly appreciable.
Thankyou

Comment: I don't think you can. Each js file in node is executed in it's own scope, so `module.exports` in a file is for that specific file only. You  can't change some other file's `module.exports`.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I found after googling n all. And it was the sole purpose of implementing modules n something like that. But there should be a way where at least i can observe some changes and impose my changes. thanks for responding @ laggingreflex

Comment: Well, as far as actually changing `module1.js` goes, you can't unless you actually, change the file `module1.js` itself. Otherwise you can make a "wrapper" module in a file `module1_change.js` and make your changes there. Wherever you would've required `module1.js`, now you require `module1_change.js` instead. Does that sound like it could work for you?

Comment: That's origin of the problem  ,which led me  to create the question here. I don't have access to know  where they can probably use module1. That's the only reason I want to change it (like overriding), so that in the sequence of the execution, my override would work.
Thanks for replying.